# Try to setup Backstage.io in AWS linux EC2 Instance Error Shown after run the command npx @backstage/create-app@latest

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, portal, backstage

Error showing while run this command @backstage/create-app@latest

1. JS stacktrace --->
2. 
3. FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
4. 1: 0xb95be0 node::Abort() [node]
5. 2: 0xa9a7f8  [node]
6. 3: 0xd6f5b0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
7. 4: 0xd6f957 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
8. 5: 0xf4ceb5  [node]
9. 6: 0xf5f38d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
10. 7: 0xf39a7e v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
11. 8: 0xf3ae47 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
12. 9: 0xf1b3c0 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
13. 10: 0xf1298c v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawArray(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
14. 11: 0xf2df1a v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::PropertyArray> v8::internal::Factory::CopyArrayAndGrow<v8::internal::PropertyArray>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::PropertyArray>, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
15. 12: 0x115c61c v8::internal::JSObject::MigrateToMap(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int) [node]
16. 13: 0x119059e v8::internal::LookupIterator::ApplyTransitionToDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>) [node]
17. 14: 0x11a9b7d v8::internal::Object::TransitionAndWriteDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin) [node]
18. 15: 0x11c1ea3 v8::internal::Object::AddDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin, v8::internal::EnforceDefineSemantics) [node]
19. 16: 0x11c2cf6 v8::internal::Object::SetProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>) [node]
20. 17: 0x12eb105 v8::internal::Runtime::SetObjectProperty(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>) [node]
21. 18: 0x115ceb4 v8::internal::JSReceiver::SetOrCopyDataProperties(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertiesEnumerationMode, v8::base::ScopedVector<v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object> > const*, bool) [node]
22. 19: 0x12eef8d v8::internal::Runtime_SetDataProperties(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
23. 20: 0x170e079  [node]
24. yarn install v1.22.22
25. [1/5] Validating package.json...
26. [2/5] Resolving packages...
27. [3/5] Fetching packages...
28. executing     yarn install ✖
29. 
30. Error: Could not execute command yarn install
31. 
32. It seems that something went wrong when creating the app
33. 
34. Failed to create app!

- Try to setup Backstage.io in AWS linux EC2 Instance Error Shown after run the command npx @backstage/create-app@latest

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to setup backstage to develop portal and i am trying this in Linux Aws EC2 install and error shows that i mentioned above